# Birds Started a Garden

Tags: identification

[image: squash type plant]
[image: squash type plant]

I have a flower bed in front of my house and I also feed birds there. I only feed packaged wild bird seed in the feeder. This plant started growing there and I'm sure it is a vegetable but not sure. I've narrowed it down to either pumpkin or some kind of squash or gourd. I think a bird must of planted the seed. Any ideas? [image]

Comment: Bird seed may contains them: they have a lot of nutrients (and so we uses them also for human food). If you have a photo of the seeds, we may get some further information (I'm thinking more about pumpkins (large seeds)/cucumbers (long seed)). In any case, as the answer below: in few weeks you will start to see the fruit, and so you can identify it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a zucchini.  But it could also be one of several squash or pumpkin types.

You should be able to tell fairly soon. You've got a fairly healthy plant there. Soon you should see a flower, which will attract honey bees. Zucchini need pollinators to form fruit. And they are not self pollinators, so with one plant you may not get any fruit.

If it came from a bird carried seed from somebody's garden, you might or might not get fruit. If its ancestors were hybrid, this one might not be able to grow fruit.

If it is a zucchini it might grow to about twice as big as it is now, not much more. If it is a squash or pumpkin, it could get several times as long as it is now. You can safely move the vines around so it's convenient. All of them will have similar flowers. They will stay green right to frost.

[image]

Comment: I added some pictures that might help